# How to exit a combat system?

Tags: python

I have been working through the Python the Hard way book and it posed the challenge to write a combat system

I am wondering how to break the while loop for a 'win' clause or to move to the next scene.
Currently the game works when the user 'dies' but in the event of beating both opponents game ends with an error message.

```
File "fight_test.py", line 146, in <module>
  a_game.play() 
File "fight_test.py", line 20, in play
  next_scene_name = current_scene.enter() 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'enter'
```

---

```
 while health > 0 and (customer1 or customer2):
            #While loop runs whilst health > 0 and one of the customers remains.
            print "\n", "-" * 20
            your_attack = randint(4,12)
            customer1_attack = randint(1,4)
            customer2_attack = randint(3,6)
            if customer2_hitpoints == 0 and customer1_hitpoints == 0:
                return 'Win'

            attack = int(raw_input("Type 1 to attack Customer 1, 2 to attack Customer 2 >"))
            if attack == 1:
                if customer1:
                    customer1_hitpoints = customer1_hitpoints - your_attack
                    print "You refuse service to Customer 1, %d damage." % your_attack
                    if customer1_hitpoints <= 0:
                        customer1 = False
                        print "Customer 1 is removed from the building."
                else:
                    print "Customer 1 has already been removed and left an angry Trip Advisor review."
            elif attack == 2:
                if customer2:
                    customer2_hitpoints = customer2_hitpoints - your_attack
                    print "You tell customer 2 that they have had too much already, %d damage." % your_attack
                    if customer2_hitpoints <= 0:
                        customer2 = False
                        print "Customer 2 falls over and throws up, they are promptly removed from the building."
                else:
                    print "They have already left to get a late night burger."
            else:
                print "Why are you just doing nothing?"

            if customer1:
                health = health - customer1_attack
                print "Customer 1 tells you that the service is better in Wetherspoons."
                print "It causes %d damage and you have d% health left." % (customer1_attack, health)
                if health <= 0:
                    return 'death'
                    break

            if customer2:
                health = health - customer2_attack
                #print Fight.quotes[randint(0, len(self.quips)-1)] 
                print "The customer tells you \"This isn't how I make this drink at home!\""
                print "It causes %d damage and you have %d health left." % (customer2_attack, health)
                if health <= 0:
                    return 'death'
                    break
```

Comment: A break or return will exit the loop... You seem to already have those

Comment: whats, the issue, specifically? That's a lot of code to look through

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst it's always useful to provide the context for the code you're having trouble with, "[the more code there is to go through, the less likely people can find your problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)". Could you please try to cut this down into a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Cheers GoBusto, hopefully this is following the example a bit better. Wasn't too sure how much to put initially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are entering Fight, I believe, and `death` can be returned at some point  which will probably load that Scene...

```
scenes = {
    'fight' : Fight(),
    'death' : Death()
}
```

> How might I implement a method to exit the while loop in such a case and move to another scene/print a win statement?

How about adding `'Win' : Win()` to the scene map?

Regarding the error

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'enter'

You also might want a scene for `None` (not `'None'`) or check that your current scene exists

```
if not current_scene:
    print "Done!" 
    exit(0)
next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()
```

Also, this is actually checking if customer2 is alive and customer1 is dead

```
if customer2_hitpoints and customer1_hitpoints == 0:
```

You need to explicitly check if both are zero

Comment: Cheers cricket. I am finding that dying in the game works, and prints out the exit statements. Just added "Win" to the scene map and made the if check to see if both == 0. Sadly I still get error messages in the event of beating both enemies.

Comment: Umm. What errors?

Comment: I get this: File "fight_test.py", line 146, in <module>
    a_game.play()
  File "fight_test.py", line 20, in play
    next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'enter'

Just trying to work out now how to link it up to the 'Win' scene.

Comment: You need to check `if current_scene` before running the enter method. When a method has no return, it does a `return None`, which isn't in the scene dictionary

Comment: Thanks man, running a check on current_scene worked like a treat! Just had to find the right place in the game engine class.